# How to get author specific poll in most recent poll block?

Tags: 7, nodes, polls

I Created a poll with core module "Poll".

Can we get author of the poll  and display in Most recent poll block?

I have using `block--poll--recent.tpl.php` to theme the poll. I have tried by global user.
but how to get a poll of that user??

Answer (score -1):

As every content type polls are node then you can get the creator by get node creator :)

$title:the title of poll

```
$node = node_load(array('title' => $title, 'type' => 'poll'));
$userId=$node->uid;
```

not we have a userId of creator , maybe you need name  or anything of it that you can get them by `user_load($userId);`

Comment: thanks for reply but.. In block--poll--recent.tpl.php, we can't get node object. So this will not work.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash, yes we can my friend, also you can put it in preprocessor and pass it as variable !!!